# How to have a div fill the whole height of its parent column in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to have the div with the red border to be the same height as its green counterpart on the right? This is in bootstrap 4!

Have tried display: flex and flex-grow, have also tried putting the border on the column (which makes the effect I'm looking for) but it then doesn't have the padding.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-1">
      <div class="border border-lg border-success p-3 p-md-4 p-lg-5 text-xlarge font-weight-medium">This is an example sentence. It may go on for a couple of lines just to see what's going to happen!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-3">
      <div class="text-xlarge text-success mt-2"><i class="icon icon-md line-height-1">check</i> Correct</div>
      <p class="mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-large">Write a short explanation here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
      <div class="border border-lg border-danger p-3 p-md-4 p-lg-5 text-xlarge font-weight-medium">This is an example sentence.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-4">
      <div class="text-xlarge text-danger mt-2"><i class="icon icon-md line-height-1">close</i> Incorrect</div>
      <p class="mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-large">Write a short explanation here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a pen with the existing: https://codepen.io/Daggett/pen/OKJxPm

The columns are also responsive and need to stack at smaller breakpoints (hence the order-lg classes)

Comment: please share a working snippet

Comment: Just going to put this here: https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard

Comment: @Wimanicesir Great resource, not too sure how to adapt it to my use case as need the cols to stack at smaller breakpoints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add `d-flex` to the column to use the default stretch behavior and have the same height. Also add `w-100` to the element to keep it's default full width:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-1 d-flex">
      <div class="border border-lg border-success p-3 p-md-4 p-lg-5 text-xlarge font-weight-medium w-100">This is an example sentence. It may go on for a couple of lines just to see what's going to happen!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-3">
      <div class="text-xlarge text-success mt-2"><i class="icon icon-md line-height-1">check</i> Correct</div>
      <p class="mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-large">Write a short explanation here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-2 d-flex">
      <div class="border border-lg border-danger p-3 p-md-4 p-lg-5 text-xlarge font-weight-medium w-100">This is an example sentence.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-4">
      <div class="text-xlarge text-danger mt-2"><i class="icon icon-md line-height-1">close</i> Incorrect</div>
      <p class="mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-large">Write a short explanation here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 rows and col-elements already have an equal height through their flex design. You only have to set the height of your inner div to 100%, to make it fill its parent space.
You can use the Bootstrap 4 `h-100` class for `height:100%;`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-1">
      <div class="border border-lg border-success p-3 p-md-4 p-lg-5 text-xlarge font-weight-medium">This is an example sentence. <br> It may go on for a couple of lines just to see what's going to happen!</div>
    </div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-3">
  <div class="text-xlarge text-success mt-2"><i class="icon icon-md line-height-1">check</i> Correct</div>
    <p class="mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-large">Write a short explanation here</p>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
  <div class="h-100 border border-lg border-danger p-3 p-md-4 p-lg-5 text-xlarge font-weight-medium">This is an example sentence.</div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-4">
  <div class="text-xlarge text-danger mt-2"><i class="icon icon-md line-height-1">close</i> Incorrect</div>
    <p class="mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-large">Write a short explanation here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the h-100 takes the height of the page, not of the col - try it out

Comment: i tryed it wihin your snippet and it works when it is applied to the inner div

Comment: Hm weird for me it makes the div film the whole page